# inb4 The popular "guessing game"

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, scope

It's not terribly distinct from us: We're in Private Beta, and Open Beta (assuming we make it there) is not very far. Sites like Anime & Manga / Gardening Stack Exchange are all falling into the ring of guessing: Interesting questions dim out and the ones that don't are the fun and games.

Allow me to quote from [The Stack Exchange Blog, Let’s Play The Guessing Game](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/):

> Guessing game questions aren't practical
>
> Guessing game questions don't help others
>
> Guessing game questions are unfair
>
> Guessing game questions aren't educational

Okay, this makes a lot of sense. But wait! Here on music fans, the topic we discuss seem to be fortunate on the aspect, as:

1. As music fans, we may have more experience on discussing about the songs, therefore leaving constructive conversations related to guesses we make, ideally backed by solid, rewarding information.
2. **Existing lyrics documentation, reflection and "the meaning" music fan blogs are weak and quite poor.** If we can come up with a proper format, it would help others who look for them.
3. Songs may be formulaic, and occasionally songs may reference each other or have common lyrics, but most songs has its own theme and therefore lyrics are different. Guesses wouldn't be absolutely subjective then. Additionally, **guessing songs may build a popular repository of songs that other searchers may be looking for** — isn't that practical?

But the fourth point is a serious problem: **"Guessing game questions aren't educational"**. In fact, it's very difficult to make *any* kind of subjective topic educational. So, can we make it work and build a functional standard that makes the site work well with guessing games?

Comment: What do you mean by guessing games? I haven't heard or seen the term on the SE network myself.

Comment: @Kevin http://i.stack.imgur.com/jQo80.png

Comment: I ignore the `identify-this-*` tags on Movies&Tv because it's full of noise and terrible questions. I vote no to `identify-this-song` questions.

Comment: I'm having a bit of difficulty understanding what activity you are referring to specifically. Is this any different than *this* conversation? http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/34/identify-this-song-genre-artist-on-topic

Answer (score 7):

> As music fans, we may have more experience on discussing about the songs, therefore leaving constructive conversations related to guesses we make

I don't follow.  Are you suggesting that the users of Gaming are unfamiliar with games, or that the users of Science Fiction & Fantasy are unexperienced with Sci-Fi/Fantasy works?  What makes music fans special?

> solid, rewarding information

No one doubts that these questions have value for the askers who get good answers and discover something they enjoy.  That's really not the point.  We can't be everything to everyone.

> most songs has its own theme and therefore lyrics are different. Guesses wouldn't be absolutely subjective then

What about uniqueness implies objectivity?  In fact, I would say that the more esoteric the lyrics the harder it would be to come up with a commonly-agreed-upon meaning for them.